# 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace system.windows

Tags: c#, winforms

I have just started working on c#, and was fiddling with some code sample that I got from some forum.

This code is using a namespace `using system.windows.forms` for which I am getting an error:

> Forms does not exist in the namespace system.windows.

Also I am getting some error related to undefined functions for `senddown` & `sendup` which I believe to be in the `Forms` name space.

I am using visual studio 10 (with .net frame work 4.0). Any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: Add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: Sounds like you created a WPF project rather than a Windows Forms project

Comment: @todda, thanks, that worked :)
@shf301, Yes it was a WPF project, but adding the mentioned reference worked.

Comment: For future reference, when asking an SO question, please paste the *exact* code, which is very much case-sensitive among other things...

Comment: @sara Regarding your bounty, what kind of answer are you looking for here? What "official sources" do you need? The question has clearly been answered: you cannot use items from namespaces that you have not added references to. Are you looking for a citation from the language standard that makes the same point?

Comment: i am facing this issue in console application. how can i resolve this issue. ?

Comment: i needed to introduce a build script that provided the argument `-r:System.Windows.Forms.dll` to my compiler. `mcs mycsharp.cs -r:System.Windows.Forms.dll`

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Expand the project in Solution Tree, <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> on `References`, `Add Reference`, Select `System.Windows.Forms` on `Framework` tab.

You need to add reference to some non-default assemblies sometimes.

**From comments**: for people looking for VS 2019+: Now adding project references is <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> on `Dependencies` in `Solution Explorer`.

For people looking for VS Code: [How do I add assembly references in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399545/213550)

Comment: ok that worked. I was under the impression that I already added it. Just checked it again and as expected, it was missing. Thanks :)

Comment: Right click on the **References** node under the Project.

Comment: @naXa Things changed from that time, yes

Comment: @naXa  Oh you meant "Project > Add reference" in the menu, not in the Solution Explorer windows... Also it only shows up if selecting "References > Analyzers" in the Solution Explorer windows first.

Comment: Update for people looking for VS 2019 - Now Adding Project References is Right-Click on  `Dependencies` in Solution Explorer.

Comment: How to do this in vscode?

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso https://stackoverflow.com/a/42399545/213550

Comment: @VMAtm I had already looked at this post. It did not work. I've already switched from vscode to visual studio and I'm still having problems. Anyway, thanks for the try.

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso What **exact** problem do you have?

Comment: @VMAtm Sorry for the inconvenience. I was using vscode together with unity. I was referencing the unity button as if it were a windows application button. Hence the error.

Answer (score 84):

In case someone runs into this error when trying to reference *Windows Forms* components in a .NET Core 3+ WPF app (which is actually not uncommon), the solution is to go into the `.csproj` file (double click it in VS2019) and add it to the property group node containing the target frameworks. Like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution that worked for me. Many of the proposed solutions I was seeing suggested adding a reference to "System.Window.Forms", but that proposal never worked for me.  I was able to add that reference and resolve my missing Forms class, but by adding that reference, it broke "System.Window"

Comment: Strange, it works on one computer, but open on another and it failed. The solution was UseWindowsForms tag. You would think with the problems of Windows Forms in .net core, Visual Studio would offer something more useful in both error finding and letting you add forms in the gui without having to close, manually edit and reload...

Comment: Thanks. Also, It was necessary for me to change targetframework from net5.0 to net5.0-windows.

Comment: @mfvjunior, yes, full explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66098428/842935

Comment: Used this answer to use old MS C# example code (aimed at 4.0) with Net 7.0. Only other thing I needed to do was to resolve an ambiguity with `Application`, by fully qualifying it with `System.Windows.Forms.Application`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/aa480727(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 20):

If you are writing **Windows Forms** code in a **.Net Core** app, then it's very probable that you run into this error:

> Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

If you are using the Sdk style project file (which is recommended) your *.csproj file should be similar to this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <RootNamespace>MyAppNamespace</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>MyAppName</AssemblyName>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="3.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Pay extra attention to these lines:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" Version="3.0.0" />
```

Note that if you are using WPF while referencing some WinForms libraries you should add `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` as well.

Hint: Since **.NET 5.0**, Microsoft recommends to refer to SDK `Microsoft.Net.Sdk` in lieu of `Microsoft.Net.Sdk.WindowsDesktop`.

Answer (score 14):

## Net >= 5

```xml
<TargetFramework>
   net5.0-windows
</TargetFramework>
```

Quoting [Announcing .NET 5.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-5-0/):

> Windows desktop APIs (including Windows Forms, WPF, and WinRT) will **only be available when targeting net5.0-windows**. You can specify an operating system version, like net5.0-windows7 or net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0 ( for Windows October 2018 Update). You need to target a Windows 10 version if you want to use WinRT APIs.

In your project:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Also interesting:

- net5.0 is the new Target Framework Moniker (TFM) for .NET 5.0.
- net5.0 combines and replaces netcoreapp and netstandard TFMs.
- net5.0 supports .NET Framework compatibility mode
- **net5.0-windows will be used to expose Windows-specific functionality, including Windows Forms, WPF and WinRT APIs.**
- **.NET 6.0 will use the same approach, with net6.0, and will add net6.0-ios and net6.0-android.**
- The OS-specific TFMs can include OS version numbers, like net6.0-ios14.
- Portable APIs, like ASP.NET Core will be usable with net5.0. The same will be true of Xamarin forms with net6.0.

Answer (score 2):

You may encounter this problem if you have multiple projects inside a solution and one of them is physically located inside solution folder.
I solved this by right click on this folder inside Solution tree -> then pressing "exclude from project"

[image: exclude folder]

Answer (score 0):

For some one just need the struct and some function from Windowsform namespace, you just need to change the the project to old behave.

Make DisableWinExeOutputInference true then OutputType dont be override by visual studio :D.

Dont foget set add -windows to TargetFramework

```
<PropertyGroup>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
<DisableWinExeOutputInference>true</DisableWinExeOutputInference>
<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
<StartupObject></StartupObject>
<ApplicationIcon />
</PropertyGroup>
```

here where i found them
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/5.0/sdk-and-target-framework-change

Answer (score -1):

```
browxy.com 
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
main.cs(7,24): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Forms' does not exist in the namespace `System.Windows'. Are you missing `System.Windows.Forms' assembly reference?
```

[image: browxy.com]

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

The cleanest solution is to add this nuget package
[Link to nuget pacakge page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Core.System.Configuration.Install)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34047901)

Comment: I forgot the details of the context that led to this post however from what I remember I was stuck in a situation where I could not reference Forms in my project (old .Net4.8 framework so this solution probably does not apply to other frameworks - poster is using 4.0) and the mentionned nuget package solved the issue.