# Using System.Windows.Forms gives me an error message

Tags: c#

> "The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace
>   'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

I'm sorry, this is probably a dumb question but I'm totally new to C# and visual studio.

Any suggestions on how to fix this ?
I need this for a plugin in Revit.

Comment: add `using System.Windows.Forms;` at the top of your code. Or right click on the error code and select "Resolve". Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6639468/c-forms-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-windows

Comment: So have you added a reference to the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly in your code? What project type did you create?

Comment: [How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Comment: Right click on your project-> Add Reference -> .Net -> System.Windows.Forms

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out. I need to add a reference to my project in the solution tree.

Sorry about that